# Dividing two rows in SAS

Tags: sas, divide

I want to create new columns by dividing existing rows.
The code for the table is as follows:

```
DATA WORK.dataset;
  INPUT      Case1 Case2  Case3  Kat$;
   datalines;
10 100 1000 A
2 2 2 B
;
```

And I want my result to be a data table that looks like this:

```
CaseX1   CaseX2   CaseX3
5        50       500
```

So I want one column to be divided by the other.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you done any research on potential approaches to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

A way out could be working with proc transpose to work with columns and then use SQL to do the trick as following:

```
DATA WORK.dataset;
  INPUT      Case1 Case2  Case3  Kat$;
   datalines;
10 100 1000 A
2 2 2 B
;

/*Taking only numeric columns*/
data want_num(keep=_NUMERIC_) want_char(keep=_CHARACTER_);
    set work.dataset;
run;

/*Transposing dataset */
proc transpose data=work.want_num out= work.dataset1(drop=_:);
run;
/*Calculating the division*/
proc sql;
create table work.dataset2 as
select  col1/col2 as Case1X
from work.dataset1;
quit;
/*Transposing back*/
proc transpose data= work.dataset2 out= res(drop=_:) prefix=CaseX;
run;
```

Cheers!